# Calling javascript function with Eval function as argument from Asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to do something like

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("data")>' onblur="jsMethod('<%#Eval("data")>')"/>
```

but unable to get it right. any help??

Answer (score 1):

`onblur` will be called on the client side, when the user input loses focus.

The `this` object could be used to refer to the input while calling the `jsMethod`.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("data")%>' onblur="jsMethod(this)"/>

function jsMethod(input)
{
    var currentText = input.value;
}
```

Comment: Although it does change the semantics, which may or may not be right.. (+1 because from the ambiguous post this could very well be correct)

Comment: Good alternative, but OP just had syntax errors on matching % signs.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. But, onBlur most checks would require the current value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write this:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("data") %>' onblur="jsMethod('<%#Eval("data")%>')" />
```

You are missing % sign in the end that's what i believe

**Update:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("data") %>' onblur='<%# @"jsMethod(""" + Eval("data")  + @""");" %>' />
```